# Is there a way to tell my app which UIWindow should determine the status bar orientation?

Tags: ios, screen-orientation, uiwindow

I have an app where the main content is presented in a window that supports all interface orientations, and some content is presented in another window that only supports portrait. This mostly works fine, except that when the device is rotated into landscape while the portrait window is being presented, the status bar still rotates to landscape (while the content stays in portrait).

This is true even if the all-orientations window is hidden, and even if it has never been made key. Is this a bug in iOS? I would think that the key window should determine the status bar orientation.

This is a minimal app that demonstrates the problem:

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var allOrientationsWindow: UIWindow!
    var portraitWindow: UIWindow!

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        self.allOrientationsWindow = createOrientationWindow(.All)
        self.allOrientationsWindow.hidden = true
        self.portraitWindow = createOrientationWindow(.Portrait)

        self.portraitWindow.makeKeyAndVisible()
        return true
    }

    func createOrientationWindow(orientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask) -> UIWindow {
        let window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
        let viewController = OrientationsViewController(orientations: orientations)
        window.rootViewController = viewController
        viewController.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

        return window
    }

}

class OrientationsViewController: UIViewController {

    var supportedOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask

    init(orientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask) {
        self.supportedOrientations = orientations
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 50, height: 50))
        label.text = "Hello"
        self.view.addSubview(label)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return self.supportedOrientations
    }

    override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
        return false
    }

}
```

This is the output:

[image: Screenshot demonstrating the issue]

Answer (score 0):

From Docs:

> Typically, the system calls this method only on the **root view**
>   **controller** of the window or a view controller presented to fill the
>   entire screen; child view controllers use the portion of the window
>   provided for them by their parent view controller and no longer
>   participate directly in decisions about what rotations are supported.
>   The intersection of the app's orientation mask and the view
>   controller's orientation mask is used to determine which
>   orientations a view controller can be rotated into.

Is this controller embedded in anything? Or do any of these other conditions not agree with your situation?

Also, have you instead attempted to use 
`- application:supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:` in `AppDelegate`?

Comment: As far as I can tell you can't set `supportedInterfaceOrientations` directly. It's a method you have to override, not a property.

Comment: I see that - adding to answer.

Comment: Both of these view controllers are set as the root view controller of their window, so they would both seem to satisfy this condition. What's unsaid here is what happens when there are multiple windows. Which window determines the status bar orientation?

Comment: Updated answer again, but could your calling window still be visible? Perhaps you could use the AppDelegate method to dig in and see which one is reported as the root controller? (It might be the one who has all rotations ok)